# Take specific build of snapshot from Gradle cache

Tags: gradle

Maven stores locally in .m2 all downloaded builds for one SNAPSHOT version into the same directory by appending a timestamp and build number to an artifact name. So later I can take any build that is available from that directory.

Can I do the same with Gradle? Can I find a specific build artifact of a SNAPSHOT version?

Comment: You can have Gradle publish a new artifact each build to your local `.m2`. You could also have Gradle just build a different JAR name into its own `build/` directory. There are multiple ways of producing a new JAR for each build or version or whatever. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My scenario is a bit uncommon. I have one dependency that resides on private Nexus. The dependency is a .tar.gz artifact. I download new builds of a SNAPSHOT version of this artifact. In `.m2` they look like: `foo-1.tar.gz`, `foo-2.tar.gz`, etc... So I can take any particular build of a SNAPSHOT version. I would like to do the same with Gradle.